# Get more trailers in Front Row

Tags: macos, mac, front-row

At trailers.apple.com I can see many more recent trailers compared to what I get in Front Row. How can I load more trailers into Front Row automatically? I don't want to download each one of them manually from the website and then go watch them in Front Row...

Comment: Questions about web applications are off topic for Super User (see the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) but on topic for the new [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) site)

Comment: Front Row is not a web application. It is a native Mac OS X application. My question is about getting it to load some additional content from the internet.

Comment: So far the only tool related to Front Row trailers is this: http://0xced.blogspot.com/2007/02/bandes-annonces-front-row.html - that at least tells me it is possible to customize it somehow..

Comment: Here's a thread listing an up-to-date feed from Apple. Perhaps that could be fed into Front Row? http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2527448&tstart=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for 4 hours in google (scanned and searched through thousands of page) , i finally figured out that **it cant be done**. Maybe Current release of Front row cannot do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The thread [Problems viewing trailers on Front Row](http://discussions.info.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2307347) is rather old, but the solution they suggested might still work.

Their cure to Front Row woes was to delete the file `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.frontrow.plist`.

You might try to rename this file and reboot. If things haven't improved, you may rename it back.

Comment: I don't think this will work in this case

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Didn't work for me.